# UIAppearance theme not applying to VC upon button tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Settings Popover VC that pops up over a MasterVC and I want to be able to pick the color theme by tapping one of 4 color selector buttons in that popover. I think I have all of the parts to the best of my ability but for some reason the screen colors are not updating - can anyone see why?

Here's my SettingsPopoverVC:

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var whiteThemeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sepiaThemeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var greyThemeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var blackThemeButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        whiteThemeButton.isSelected = true
}
}

    //MARK: - backgroundColorCell changes App color theme
    @IBAction func whiteThemeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if whiteThemeButton.isSelected == true {
            whiteThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }else {
            Theme.default.apply()
            whiteThemeButton.isSelected = true
            sepiaThemeButton.isSelected = false
            greyThemeButton.isSelected = false
            blackThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sepiaThemeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sepiaThemeButton.isSelected == true {
            sepiaThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }else {
            Theme.sepia.apply()
            whiteThemeButton.isSelected = false
            sepiaThemeButton.isSelected = true
            greyThemeButton.isSelected = false
            blackThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func greyThemeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if greyThemeButton.isSelected == true {
            greyThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }else {
            Theme.grey.apply()
            whiteThemeButton.isSelected = false
            sepiaThemeButton.isSelected = false
            greyThemeButton.isSelected = true
            blackThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func blackThemeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if blackThemeButton.isSelected == true {
            blackThemeButton.isSelected = false
        }else {
            Theme.black.apply()
            whiteThemeButton.isSelected = false
            sepiaThemeButton.isSelected = false
            greyThemeButton.isSelected = false
            blackThemeButton.isSelected = true
        }
}
```

And then I have a Theme.swift where I set each color option and the apply() method:

```
import UIKit

enum Theme: Int {
    case `default`, sepia, grey, black

    private enum Keys {
        static let selectedTheme = "SelectedTheme"
    }

    static var current: Theme {
        let storedTheme = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: Keys.selectedTheme)
        return Theme(rawValue: storedTheme) ?? .default
    }

    var mainColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            print("/default")
            return UIColor(red: 87.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .sepia:
            return UIColor(red: 87.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .grey:
            return UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 115.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .black:
            return UIColor(red: 10.0/255.0, green: 10.0/255.0, blue: 10.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }

    var backgroundColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            return UIColor.white
        case .sepia:
            return UIColor.primarySepia
        case .grey:
            return UIColor.primarySlate
        case .black:
            return UIColor.black
        }
    }

    var textColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            return UIColor.primarySlate
        case .sepia:
            return UIColor.primarySlate
        case .grey:
            return UIColor.white
        case .black:
            return UIColor.white
        }
    }

    func apply() {
        UITextView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MasterViewController.self]).textColor = textColor
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MasterViewController.self]).backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MasterViewController.self]).textColor = textColor
        UISlider.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MasterViewController.self]).minimumTrackTintColor = textColor
        UISlider.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MasterViewController.self]).maximumTrackTintColor = textColor

    }
}
```

The Theme works when I apply Theme.sepia.apply() directly to the MasterVC in its viewDidLoad, but not from the SettingsPopover. I thought because I am setting the appearance with (whenContainedInInstancesOf: ), it should apply it to that VC no matter where its being called. But that does not seem to be case. Can anyone spot my issue?

Comment: The `appearance` settings only apply to views created afterwards. Existing views are not affected by changes to `appearance`.

Comment: Is there a different way to accomplish a color selector like this? I am trying to replicate the color selector in Apple's iBooks app like this - https://imgur.com/a/vMbvuxT

Answer (score 0):

As you’ve been told, the appearance proxy does not affect existing interface. You just have to do this the same way Superman gets into his tights, one leg at a time. When the user changes the theme, cycle recursively through everything in the visible interface (every view and bar item) and change it, yourself.

Comment: Noob question for clarification: by cycle recursively through everything in the visible interface, do you mean that instead of calling say Theme.sepia.apply(), I should instead of set the color of each view/item in my viewcontroller like textview.textColor = white, etc ... right?

Comment: Exactly, just walk the views one at a time, look at what each one is, and change it accordingly.